# How to render freemarker templates that have a symlink in their path?

Tags: java, content-management-system, symlink, freemarker

I am trying to use FreeMarker to render some templates that come from a CMS path that happens to include a symbolic link (under Linux).  Our CMS code handles the path to the template so, for example, this path:

```
/var/cms/live/display/main.html
```

really points to:

```
/var/cms/trunk/127/display/main.html
```

`/var/cms/live` is the base-directory while `/display/main.html` is the path.

In my case, `live` is a symbolic link -- in this case to `trunk/127`.  FYI: the trunk is our SVN branch.  When our CMS system downloads a new release of CMS files as (for example) `trunk-128.zip`, it unpacks it into `trunk/128` and then changes the symlink (atomically) to `trunk/128`.  Great.

The problem is that FreeMarker seems to have cached the `trunk/127` path.  It doesn't recognize that the file `/var/cms/live/display/main.html` has been updated and if the `trunk/127` tree is removed, it generates a 500 error.

```
500 Unable to load template: /display/main.html
```

How can I get FreeMarker to cache the proper path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem turned out to be with FreeMarker's `FileTemplateLoader` class.  It does a `baseDir.getCanonicalFile(...)` call on the base-directory passed into the constructor.  When our application booted, the base directory `/var/cms/live` gets resolved into the real path `/var/cms/trunk/127/` by `getCanonicalFile(...)` so any future changes to the symlink are ignored.

It does this in the constructor, so we were forced to create our own `LocalFileTemplateLoader` which is listed below.

It is just a basic spring loaded implementation of `TemplateLoader`.  Then when we are building our FreeMarker Configuration we set the template loader:

```
 Configuration config = new Configuration();
 LocalTemplateLoader loader = new LocalTemplateLoader();
 // this is designed for spring
 loader.setBaseDir("/var/cms/live");
 config.setTemplateLoader(loader);
 ...
```

Here is our `LocalFileTemplateLoader` code.  [Full class on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/RbGPRd4d):

```
public class LocalFileTemplateLoader implements TemplateLoader {

    public File baseDir;

    @Override
    public Object findTemplateSource(String name) {
        File source = new File(baseDir, name);
        if (source.isFile()) {
            return source;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public long getLastModified(Object templateSource) {
        if (templateSource instanceof File) {
            return new Long(((File) templateSource).lastModified());
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("templateSource is an unknown type: " + templateSource.getClass());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Reader getReader(Object templateSource, String encoding) throws IOException {
        if (templateSource instanceof File) {
            return new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream((File) templateSource), encoding);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("templateSource is an unknown type: " + templateSource.getClass());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void closeTemplateSource(Object templateSource) {
        // noop
    }

    @Required
    public void setBaseDir(File baseDir) {
        this.baseDir = baseDir;
        // it may not exist yet because CMS is going to download and create it
    }
}
```